# how can I mask an image layer with vector layer in openalyer 6?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have an image layer with an image in rectangle shape. I want to mask this image with a vector layer, to make it fit inside the boundary. I have tried this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185881/clipping-tilelayer-with-georeferenced-polygon-clipping-mask
but it seems like a normal vecotr layer overlay. I want to mask an imagelayer.
My imagelayer is :

```
var ext = [677276.6184634935, 998535.6531789962, 680930.1784387273, 1001712.63214407];    
var imageLayer = new ImageLayer({
    source : new Static({
    title: 'imageee',
    url: '/static/wetlandapp/images/idw/idw.png',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    projection: 'EPSG:32643',
    imageExtent: ext,
    imageSmoothing: true, 
    }),
    //opacity: 0.9,
  });     
map.addLayer(imageLayer);
map.getView().fit(ext);
```

I have added masking using ol-ext as below:

```
var dep = data.features[0];
var coords = dep.geometry.coordinates;
var f = new Feature(new MultiPolygon(coords));
var maskk = new Mask({ feature: f, inner:false, fill: new Fill({ color:[255,255,255,0.8] }) }); //, opacity: 0.1
imageLayer.addFilter(maskk);
maskk.fillColor_ = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.2)';
maskk.set('active', true);
```

and the output is [image]

And added layer clipping as below:

```
var clipLayer = new VectorLayer({
        style: null,
        source: new VectorSource({
        features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, {
                    dataProjection: 'EPSG:32643',
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:32643',
                }),
        }),
    });
    clipLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function () {
      imageLayer.setExtent(clipLayer.getSource().getExtent());
    });

    var style = new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: 'black',
      }),
    });

    imageLayer.on('postrender', function (e) {
      var vectorContext = getVectorContext(e);
      e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
      clipLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
        vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, style);
      });
      e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    });
    map.addLayer(clipLayer);
```

And the output is:
[image]

The problem is in clipping, layers in all other area is not visible. while in masking , the image layer is not masked completed, but all other layers are visible.
I want an output like in clipping with all other layers enabled/ should be visible.

Comment: You could base it on this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html

Comment: @Mike I have tried it. but the problem only clipped area is visible, layer outside clipping area is not visible. Also tried ol-ext masking. https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html I have updated the question. please have a look.

Comment: It look like your layers are sharing a canvas.  Set a className on the image layer so it has its own canvas.

Comment: Wow Great !!..it worked !! My problem is solved :-)

Comment: @Mike I have changed from 'png' to 'tif' image. Now the same problem arise, layer outside clipping area is not visible. while masking. It uses **ol/source/ImageStatic** so I can't add className to it.I followed this https://github.com/pbabik/webraster/blob/master/index.html

Comment: You could set in in `const geotiffLayer = new ol.layer.Image({className: 'myClassName'});`

Comment: @Mike Wow..Worked perfectly. :-)

Comment: @Mike When I tried to print the above masked layer is not getting in the print, all other layers are getting. I added 'title' to the imagelayer & cliplayer, but it didn't worked. I am using this export https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html

Comment: You will need your own classname as well as .ol-layer in the querySelectorAll list.  Also make sure the canvas is not tainted (specify `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` in the source options).

Comment: I added my ownclassname with .ol-layer & got printed. ***const geotiffLayer = new ImageLayer({className: 'myClassName ol-layer'});*** Is this okay? Its working with this

Comment: Adding a className to the layer absolutely works. This is very interesting to me. Why does this work and what are the side effects to giving a layer a className? It's such an odd and instant fix but it works quite well I'm skeptical LOL.